# relative achievement reinforcing views on self-efficacy

Tags: cognitive-psychology

What is the impact of relative achievement in a topic on self-efficacy in that topic.

For example I have the same self-efficacy in two subjects X and Y and sit tests in both. I get more questions right in X than Y, but I get given a higher grade in Y than X.

Would my self efficacy be impacted more by the higher grade, or by the higher number of questions I get right. What would be the impact of the grade allocation be on self-efficacy in both subjects?

E.g. Bandura, A. (1982). Self-efficacy mechanism in human agency. American Psychologist, 37(2), 122-147.
http://dx.doi.org/10.1037/0003-066X.37.2.122

Comment: It is very hard to understand your question. What is 'relative achievement'? How should we interpret "in a topic .. in that topic"? In addition, could you include a reference to how you interpret self-efficacy? We expect questions to be framed in psychology or neuroscience. Making this reference explicit would greatly improve your question.

Comment: But, after digesting your question a bit. In short, your main question seems to be: "How do grades affect self-efficacy?" Is this correct? (you can edit your question) The 'relative' part and whether or not grading corresponds to actual knowledge seem to be related sub-questions. What do you already know on this topic, and what is your motivation for asking?

Comment: I suppose that is the core of it. I've been looking a bit at grading systems in the UK, and for some subjects students are graded more harshly than others (so it appears). I'm interested in whether a central decision to raise the grades for students would result in their performance increasing, related to bandera's self efficacy theory. I'm familiar with Bandera, but have been looking for some research that answers this sepecific question. Apologies, I'm new here!